# Creating secondary dropdownlist based off first dropdown list pulled back from db using php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have managed to get the first db list working but I don't know how to go about making a secondary dropdown based off the first one.  Maybe a filtered version of the first dropdownlist?  Here's the code that I have so far:

```
<?php
require '/dbinfo/oracconnect.php';
include 'myfunctions.php';

if(isset($_POST['location'])) {

$loc_data = explode("|", $_POST['location']);

$mo_in_out = array();
$mo_in_out = getMOs($loc_data[0]);

echo "Movement Orders for ".$loc_data[1]."</br><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Target</td><td>Source</td></tr>";
$i = sizeof($mo_in_out);
$ii=0;
while($ii < $i)
{
    echo"<tr><td>". $mo_in_out[$ii] ."</td><td>".$mo_in_out[$ii+1]."</td></tr>";
    $ii = $ii + 2;
}
echo "</table>";

if (isStorage($loc_data[0]) == 1){  
    echo "Unique SKU count: ".countUnique($loc_data[0]) . "for ".$loc_data[1];  //calls a function countUnique() - useful to use functions as they can be reused and used between pages
    echo "</br>". "Empties:" .emptyLUs($loc_data[0]);
    $filldata = fillperc($loc_data[1]);
    echo "</br>Fill:" . $filldata[3] ."%";
    echo "</br>Total Locations:" . $filldata[1];
    $coMo = completeMO($loc_data[1]);
    echo "</br>Complete MO's". $coMo[0];
}

echo"</br></br>";
}

else{  // display this stuff if button hasn't been clicked.

$conn = prod_conn();

$loc = array();
$loc = getLocations();
$i = $i = sizeof($loc);

?>
<html>
<img src="header.jpg" alt="SSI Schaefer logo"      style="width:1580px;height:50px;"><head><B>Impact Assessment Matrix</B></head>
<title>Impact Assessment Matrix</title>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">  

<p>
Select location.....

<?php

$ii = 0;
echo"<select name='location' id='location'>";   //     onchange='this.form.submit();'>"; // can be added to allow changing value to trigger data submission
echo"<option value=''>Select...</option>";
while($ii < $i)
{
echo"<option value='".$loc[$ii] ."|".$loc[$ii+1]."'>".$loc  [$ii+1]."</option>";
$ii = $ii + 2;
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"Results\" value=\"Results\"   onclick=\"this.form.submit();\"/>";
}
?>

</p>
</form>
</html>
```

This brings back the option list from the db but don't where to start when filtering this list into other dropdown lists.  Can anybody help please?

Comment: You need to learn some javascript with specific attention to AJAX.

Comment: So I can't filter the dropdownlist I already have from the db using php?

Comment: You cannot do anything to load the second list until you know what was select in the first list, so you need to request the second list when the user selects from the first list.

Comment: I do not want to select from the first list, I would just like to create other dropdowns with filtered versions of the options in the first dropdown e.g. my first list has all the 'locations' listed from that table and I would like do some kind of wildcard filter on this list when creating the other dropdowns.